# PHP DOM remove child

Tags: php, xml, dom, simplexml

I am trying to remove the parent node of `<wcccanumber>` from my xml, if it's content matches a certain criterion, but it keeps just removing the one node `<wcccanumber>`. How do I remove the whole parent node?

Heres my code:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<xml/>');

if (file_exists("xml/units/E01.xml")) {

    $xml = simplexml_load_file("xml/units/E01.xml");

    echo "File exists";
    echo "</br>";

    $wcccanumber = "121202482";

    foreach ($xml->call->wcccanumber as $call) {
        if ($call == $wcccanumber) {
            $dom = dom_import_simplexml($call);
            $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);

            $fp = fopen("xml/units/E01.xml","wb");
            fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
            fclose($fp);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xml:

```
<xml>
  <call>
     <wcccanumber>121202482</wcccanumber>
     <currentcall>FALL</currentcall>
     <county>W</county>
     <id>82</id>
     <location>234 E MAIN ST</location>
     <callcreated>12:26:09</callcreated>
     <station>HBM</station>
     <units>E01</units>
     <calltype>M</calltype>
     <lat>45.5225067888299</lat>
     <lng>-122.987112718574</lng>
     <inputtime>12/18/2012 12:27:01 pm</inputtime>
  </call>
</xml>
```

Comment: You want to remove all children of call, right?

Comment: Yes I do and then I will right more code to replace, but I can't figure out how to remove them yet.

Comment: I ultimately want to remove the WHOLE <call> node, including call

Comment: psst: http://php.net/file_put_contents

Comment: thanks. works 10x better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate through `call` and compare `$call->wcccanumber` with `$wcccanumber`. Convert `$call` to dom and remove it (`parentNode->removeChild`).

```
foreach ($xml->call as $call) {
    if ($call->wcccanumber == $wcccanumber) {
        $dom = dom_import_simplexml($call);
        $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
        $fp = fopen("xml/units/E01.xml","wb");
        fwrite($fp,$xml->asXML());
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

If there are multiple deletions it makes sense to save only once *after* all deletions have been done.

```
$deletionCount = 0;

foreach ($xml->call as $call) {
    if ($call->wcccanumber != $wcccanumber) {
        continue;
    }
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($call);
    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    $deletionCount++;
}

if ($deletionCount) {
    file_put_contents("xml/units/E01.xml", $xml->asXML());
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. thanks. I don't know what I can't think of that on my own...

Comment: Sometimes can't see the forest for its trees :)

Comment: Well, actually, if there are one or multiple deletions, you should save *after* the `foreach` so that you always save once all changes.

Comment: So this deletes the "<xml>" bracket but leaves the "</xml>" bracket so it ends up screwing up my code when I go to insert a new child!